Ubuntu 24.04: Oh no, something went wrong
My device is Lenovo Legion with AMD Ryzen 5 5000 series and Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050Ti. In the new Ubuntu 24.04 I changed the font in the settings. The PC then got stuck for a few seconds and then rebooted and loaded a white screen with the error message Oh no something went wrong, we cannot recover.
I tried to reinstall gnome-desktop and whatever I did after login the error persisted. I then logged in TTY3 to create a new user, logged in with the new user which was OK, but the previous user with the error desktop still gave an error message.

i have a same problem i use this solution https://linuxconfig.org/reset-gnome-desktop-settings-to-factory-default-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish
but all extension config is gone

Seems pretty clear. What ever the unnamed font is Ubuntu 24.04 does not like it. Reinstall the OS.

Not sure if this is helpful, but I ran into this error after running 24.04 clean install (not upgrade from older distro) for >2 weeks, while working daily on the laptop.
After a few hour debugging (trying to remember everything I updated on the config the day before) I finally remembered that I updated terminal font. Not sure how something so basic could possibly trigger such a terrible "bug", but ultimately I connected to tty4 and uninstalled gnome-terminal sudo apt purge gnome-terminal (as I ran out of the ideas what to do). And suddenly it worked. After reinstalling the terminal I couldn't recreate the bug, which makes it even worse, but hopefully, over time, it will be resolved on the distro.

worked for me: purge gnome-terminal and then reinstalled, now X11 is booting. Thanks

Same experience. Purged via TTY, rebooted, reinstalled. In my case it was Wayland.
